# An Optimal Solution which Does Not Satisfy Optimality Condition

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

I read this theorem in a book about Linear Optimization:

> In the simplex method, for a minimization problem, a BFS is optimal if all of the reduced costs are negative, i.e. $\forall i \quad z_i-c_i \le 0$.

I am curious is the inverse of the above theorem also true? Or can we find an optimal solution such that $z_k-c_k>0$ for some $k$? The latter case means the simplex algorithm does not necessarily terminate when it reaches an optimal solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific by what you mean by inverse? Do you mean converse?

Comment: @PseudoLooped I do not know what you mean by the "Converse". I am asking if is there a BFS with some positive reduced cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only situation this would be true if there exists a constraint that causes degeneracy in a model where one of the basic variables has a zero as its right-hand-side value, and thus doesn’t contribute to a model upon a pivot. For example:

Suppose we have a model:

$$\text{min }z=-x_1+x_2-x_3$$

Subject to,

$$x_1+x_2\le 4$$
$$-x_2+x_3\le0$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge0$$

Converting this to standard form, we get:

$$\text{min } z +x_1 - x_2 +x_3 = 0$$

Subject to:
$$x_1+x_2+s_1=4$$
$$-x_2+x_3+s_2=0$$
$$x_1, x_2, x_3, s_1, s_2 \ge0$$

From here, lets put this in a tableau:

[image]

Let’s pivot the $x_1$ column to produce:

[image]

Then lets pivot the $x_3$ column to produce our final tableau:
[image]

Notice that the solution produced in the second tableau is optimal, $(4,0,0)$, and is exactly the same as the solution produced by the third tableau. In addition, the second tableau produced an optimal solution, but had a $C^\pi_j > 0$, which shows that the simplex method doesn’t terminate right away.

[Here’s a PowerPoint slide I found](https://web.archive.org/web/20100628062356/http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/degeneracy1.pdf) that explains more on Degeneracy in models.