# Feasible solution with strictly negative reduced costs

Tags: linear-programming

My question is:
Show that a degenerate basic feasible solution can be optimal without satisfying $r_j \geq 0$ for all $j$, i.e. there can be strictly negative reduced costs.

I can't seem to find any information regarding this. I'm having a really hard time proving this or finding a counter example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An Optimal Solution which Does Not Satisfy Optimality Condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338238/an-optimal-solution-which-does-not-satisfy-optimality-condition)

Comment: @PseudoLooped It helps a lot yes thank you !